# How to check whether any application is set to selected Mock Locations setting or not in Android Marshmallow

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, gps

*For Android Lollipop and below versions I am checking like below.*

```
if (Secure.getString(this.cordova.getActivity().getContentResolver(), Secure.ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION).equals("0")) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
```

*But for **Android M** this option is removed. Right now for **Android M** I am doing Like below. But this is not working and throwing an exception.*

```
if(Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M)
        {
            AppOpsManager opsManager = (AppOpsManager) this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
            PackageManager pm = this.cordova.getActivity().getApplicationContext().getPackageManager();
            List<ApplicationInfo> packages = pm.getInstalledApplications(PackageManager.GET_META_DATA);
            for (ApplicationInfo applicationInfo : packages) {
                if (opsManager.checkOp(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_MOCK_LOCATION, applicationInfo.uid, applicationInfo.packageName)== AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED) {
                    return true;
                    break;
                }
            }
        }
```

To Solve this issue I've read all the below links but nothing is satisfying my Requirement. My Requiremnet is, If any of the app set to use Mock Location then I should get the **true**. Based on that I will notify the user to set the option **nothing**

1. [How to read selected mock location app in Android M - API 23](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33003553/how-to-read-selected-mock-location-app-in-android-m-api-23/33066797#33066797)
2. [Disable / Check for Mock Location (prevent gps spoofing)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6880232/disable-check-for-mock-location-prevent-gps-spoofing)

Comment: did you solve it?

Comment: No. I didn't get any solution. Right now I am allowing accepting all the locations without filtering.

Comment: Do you want to fix it? 
I've fixed it and I can share my code. 
No one was buying our application due to this problem only. I somehow solved it. :D

Comment: Can you please share the code. Even for me also it is required. Thanks in Advance.