# How to check and request android permission for ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION in android API >22

Tags: android, android-manifest, android-6.0-marshmallow, android-maps-v2

I am trying to restrict Location Spoofing.

For API <= 22 it works fine but >22 it asking for permissions and **ALLOW_MOCK_LOCATION ** is deprecated.

So need solution for this

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to check for Mock Location in Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668494/how-to-check-for-mock-location-in-android-marshmallow)

Comment: @Michael I tried those things but cannot get solution.

Comment: It's unclear what you mean by _"cannot get solution"_.

Comment: Above API 22 ,I am not able to detect whether  Mock Location is Used or not due to permissions.

I got SercurityException while following Code

AppOpsManager opsManager = (AppOpsManager) context.getSystemService(Context.APP_OPS_SERVICE);
//            boolean isMockLocation = (opsManager.checkOp(AppOpsManager.OPSTR_MOCK_LOCATION, android.os.Process.myUid(), BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID)== AppOpsManager.MODE_ALLOWED);
//            return isMockLocation;

Comment: Why not just use `location.isFromMockProvider()` as was suggested on the page I linked to?

Comment: It  returning false even if I Select fake gps App in Mock Location at "Developer Option"

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148606/discussion-between-sanket-parchande-and-michael).