# Checking fake gps on Sap Fiori Client App

Tags: geolocation, android-webview, sapui5, sap-fiori

I have a Sapui5 application that runs on Sap Fiori Client App. This application uses user's location and on Andriod its very easy to fake your Gps. It there any way to detect mock gps usage on Sap Fiori Client App?

Best Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Since your application runs in an Android app and not as a native app you are not on the right level to have access to the systems settings. When developing an Android app you have some options to accomplish the detection of fake GPS (i.e *Location.isFromMockProvider()*).

For more information (Android):
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41538070/8194384

In your case the devs of the SAP Fiori Client App have to implement that feature and make it available in Fiori apps.

Alternatively you can implement a custom plausibility check to validate the GPS locations. Since SAP apps are only used in business context there should be limited scenarios that are credible. I.e: A Pokemon Go player has a "valid" reason to fake his location to be New York. I doubt that your service staff or sales reps has such motivations.

And for general considerations:
Is such a check really necessary and requested from the business? If yes, it would be their task to define what is plausible/credible and what not.