# How to detect fake location in Android?

Tags: android, location, android-location, android-gps, android-fusedlocation

I am working on an app in which I have to trace the location of drivers. I used fusedlocation and GPS location methods for this purpose. It is working fine.
But some drivers/users have installed Fake GPS/Fake Location Apps on their devices through which they are changing the location of their device.
Due to this my app is unable to get exact location, my app is getting fake location (the location that is set by fake location apps).
Is there any way to get right (current) location of the user/driver?
Is there any way to get exact current location by overriding fake gps location?
Is there any way to detect that is there any fake location app is running or not?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to check for Mock Location in Android Marshmallow?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32668494/how-to-check-for-mock-location-in-android-marshmallow)

Comment: Thanks I got some help from these